# Positioning ViewPoint within a 3D Graphic (from ParametricPlot3D) Leads to Extraneous Panels in Output

Tags: graphics3d, visualization

I am animating the ViewVector (very similar to the ViewVector Documentation "Neat Example") to follow the curve in a 3D graphic created by the ParametricPlot3D function. This is, in principle, a very nice feature! However, I find that the output is contaminated with extraneous blue panels. Here is a "toy" example of my input and output:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
xx[t_] = Cos[t];
yy[t_] = Sin[t];
zz[t_] = t;
helix = ParametricPlot3D[{xx[t], yy[t], zz[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
viewTo = {0, 0, 15};
With[{obj = helix}, 
 Animate[Show[obj, ViewVector -> {{xx[t], yy[t], zz[t]}, viewTo}], {t,
    0, 8}, AnimationRunning -> False]]
```

Output:

[image: Output]

The blue panels seen in the animated version are not seen in the non-animated version printed first, and they should not be there. I am using MMA 12.0.0 on a Mac. Does anyone know what is going wrong? Thanks for any help.

**Edit**
I have learned that this issue is not related to the animation, per se, but is present for certain cases (certainly not all) when one uses ViewVector to position one's "camera" within the volume of the graphic. Here is a new test which demonstrates this, with no animation, input then output.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
xx[t_] = Cos[t];
yy[t_] = Sin[t];
zz[t_] = t;
helix = ParametricPlot3D[{xx[t], yy[t], zz[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
viewTo = {0, 0, 15};
tt = Table[i/5, {i, 17, 24}];
Do[Print[Show[helix, 
    ViewVector -> {{xx[tt[[i]]], yy[tt[[i]]], zz[tt[[i]]]}, 
      viewTo}]], {i, 1, 8}];
```

[image]

The first figure is viewed from outside the graphic, the following eight are from various points inside the graphic, defined to be on the path of the function. I can add that the colour of the extraneous panels, in general, matches that of the plotted function.

Finally, I did another test (not shown) in which I used ViewPoint and ViewCenter separately, instead of ViewVector, to specify the view. In that case, I also got the extraneous panels for some examples with the ViewPoint set inside the figure, so this is not ViewVector per se, but seems to depend only on the location of the ViewPoint.

Is this some weird geometrical "reflection" of the line or is it a bug?

**Edit 2**
I have now filed this as a bug report.

**Edit 3**
Mathematica User Support have confirmed that this appears to be a bug and the developers will attempt to fix it for a future release of MMA. Shame they did not upvote my post.